# Replace empty elements on a list with None

Tags: list, api, null, spotify, nonetype

n_available_markets=[playlist['tracks']['items'][i]['track']['available_markets']
for i in range(len(playlist['tracks']['items']))]

for i in n_available_markets:
if i=="[]":
i==None
n_available_markets

I was working with the Spotify API and I found that some values when I created the list were empty [**[],**['NZ','ES']]  so I was wondering how I could change this empty values into None and I tried the code attached above(the first 2 lines are just to retrieve the available markets data) but it did not make any change.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```py
n_available_markets = [p['track']['available_markets'] if len(p['track']['available_markets'])>0 else None for p in playlist['tracks']['items']]
```